# R: How to combine 300 1GB .rds files into 1 large rds file without reading them into memory?

Tags: r

I have 300+ .rds files each with the same column names and would like to bind them together into a single compressed .rds file that I can transfer via sftp.

Is there a way of doing this efficiently without reading them into memory?

At the moment I'm working with the following code, but this maxes out the memory before writing the file. Any thoughts are much appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- list.files(pattern = ".rds") %>%
         map(readRDS) %>% 
         data.table::rbindlist()

    saveRDS(df,"df.rds")
```

Eventually I read in one by one and used `read::write_csv("name.csv",append=TRUE)` to append them on disk. After that I use {disk.frame} or SQL database to process the data.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't append data to an RDS file. The file format is for arbitrary R objects. Appending only is sensible for tabular data. If you use an uncompressed RDS, you *might*  be able to hack something with low level functions but that would be a significant amount of work. Cheaper to simply buy/rent more RAM.

Comment: Personally, I use CSV and simply zip it before transfer.

Comment: Even if you manage in some way to do it, how do you think that huge (300GB) file can be opened?

Comment: You mentioned that you use `disk.frame` which splits larger than memory files in smaller chuncks. Why don't you just zip the `disk.frame` folder instead of trying to create a single .rds?

Comment: @nicola. It can be streamed

Comment: @MadsBoyd-Madsen Can you add more details? I'm not familiar with streaming `rds` files. Do you have some reference on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, it probably isn't possible (or at least very difficult) to append/merge `.rds` files. However, if they are simple columns then there should be on problem converting them to `.csv`. In which case they can be appended, assuming (as you have said) they have matching column names.

This snippet reads from a list of `.rds` filenames and appends their data to a `.csv`. I've next to no R experience, so I'm not sure of how the underlying resources are managed, but in principal this method should allow you to read only one file at a time and thus keep your memory consumption at ~1GB while building your ~300GB `.csv`.

```r
fileNames <- list('test-one.rds', 'test-two.rds')

for (fileName in fileNames)
{
    rds <- readRDS(fileName)
    for (row in rds){
        write(row, file = 'out.csv', append = TRUE)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your final purpose is to transfer the data, read and write the data in sql server.

You can convert the .rds to .csv and use HeidiSQL for a quick import into a table structured as your csv.

Then on the other end, you can read the data from SQL and convert them into .rds again or just send the .csv over.